# How to Convert Columns to Rows and Replace Column Names

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a Table that returns me the Amount of products w.r.t to the Months in a row like:

```
[M02] | [M03] | [M04] | [M05] | [M06] | [M07] | [M08] | [M09] |[M10] | [M11] | [M12]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
120   | 65    | 75    | 587   | [78   | 5656  | 651   | 65    | 8949 | 89   | 596
```

now I need the result as [here I want to replace the columns into rows and change their names to the aliases of my choice] **e.g M01 to January from column to row**

```
  [Month]  | [Count] |
----------------------
  January  |     120 |
  February |     65  |
```

I know I can achieve this with the UnPivot operator but I'm unable to get the name of the months as January as I can't set alias inside the unpivot

I wrote this query

```
SELECT [Months],[Count]
  FROM [TableName]
  UnPivot(
  [Count] for Months in ([M01]
      ,[M02]
      ,[M03]
      ,[M04]
      ,[M05]
      ,[M06]
      ,[M07]
      ,[M08]
      ,[M09]
      ,[M10]
      ,[M11]
      ,[M12])
  ) as unpiv
```

this give me data as:

```
      [Month]  | [Count] |
    ----------------------
      M01      |     120 |
      M02      |     65  |
```

here M01, M02 etc are months respectively but I can't change their name. how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach 1** : Using `CASE WHEN`

You can use `CASE WHEN` like following to get the desired output.

```
SELECT    
    (CASE 
    WHEN [Months]= 'M01' then 'January'
    WHEN [Months]= 'M02' then 'February'
        --PUT Remaning conditions
    END) [Months],
    [Count]

FROM
(
SELECT [Months],[Count]
    FROM [TableName]
    UnPivot(
    [Count] for Months in ([M01]
        ,[M02]
        ,[M03]
        ,[M04]
        ,[M05]
        ,[M06]
        ,[M07]
        ,[M08]
        ,[M09]
        ,[M10]
        ,[M11]
        ,[M12])
    ) as unpiv
)T
```

**Approach 2:** `INNER JOIN` to mapping table

You can have a mapping table, where you map your codes with months and put a `INNER JOIN` like

```
SELECT 
MP.MonthName,
T.[Count]
FROM
(
SELECT [Months],[Count]
  FROM [TableName]
  UnPivot(
  [Count] for Months in ([M01]
      ,[M02]
      ,[M03]
      ,[M04]
      ,[M05]
      ,[M06]
      ,[M07]
      ,[M08]
      ,[M09]
      ,[M10]
      ,[M11]
      ,[M12])
  ) as unpiv
)t
INNER JOIN [YourMappingTable] MP ON MP.Code=T.Months
```

**Approach 3**: String functions.

Another approach can be using `RIGHT` with `PATINDEX` to get the number and finally converting the number to a month name.

```
SELECT 
DateName( month , DateAdd( month ,  CAST(RIGHT(T.[Months],PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',T.[Months])) AS INT) , 0 ) - 1 ) as Months,
[Count]
FROM
(
SELECT [Months],[Count]
  FROM [TableName]
  UnPivot(
  [Count] for Months in ([M01]
      ,[M02]
      ,[M03]
      ,[M04]
      ,[M05]
      ,[M06]
      ,[M07]
      ,[M08]
      ,[M09]
      ,[M10]
      ,[M11]
      ,[M12])
  ) as unpiv
)t
```

Note: If the format is fixed, you can also try like following without using `PATINDEX`

```
DateName( month , DateAdd( month ,  CAST(RIGHT(T.[Months],2) AS INT) , 0 ) - 1 ) as Months,
```

Comment: Thank You for a very detailed explanation. appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign an alias inside of the UNPIVOT function so you would have to use the CASE expression.